# WhatsApp spyware application through WhatsApp call

Tags: spyware, whatsapp, breach

Probably everyone heard that there was high security vulnerability in WhatsApp this week

https://www.forbes.com/sites/zakdoffman/2019/05/14/whatsapps-cybersecurity-breach-phones-hit-with-israeli-spyware-over-voice-calls/

Can anyone make me understand how it was possible to spread malicious spyware just through WhatsApp missed calls. What do you think, what's the technology can be behind it?

Any answers are appreciated.

Comment: The articles about the vulnerability explain how it is carried out: a buffer overflow in the VOIP stack.

Comment: @schroeder, do you know how/why this was marked as a duplicate of a deleted question?  I just came across [a reuters story](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-facebook-cyber-whatsapp-nsogroup/exclusive-whatsapp-hacked-to-spy-on-top-government-officials-at-u-s-allies-sources-idUSKBN1XA27H) evidently about the same exploit, and would like to read up on it here, but the link is broken.

Comment: @wildcard obviously the question was not deleted when this one was marked as a duplicate